# Use ifelse to assign Date in new factor

Tags: r, date, if-statement

I would like to assign different dates to new factor in a dataframe that is dependent upon the year of the particular observation.  Here's what I have:

```
Date     Location
2014-10-30     AB1
2014-09-02     AB3
2015-10-15     AB1
2016-11-02     AB4
etc. (191K observations)
```

And here's what I'd like to get, given I have Reference dates of 2014-08-14, 2016-09-16, etc. associated with the Year of the observation's date.  For those years without a Reference date, I'd like the value set to NA.

```
Date     Location     Reference
2014-10-30     AB1     2014-08-14
2014-09-02     AB3     2014-08-14
2015-10-15     AB1     NA
2016-11-02     AB4     2016-09-16
etc. (191K observations)
```

I know how to write the ifelse statement to specify the assignment of dates to particular years, but the syntax of identifying a particular year based on 'Date' and matching the Reference date based on that value isn't obvious to me.  I would really appreciate some guidance on this issue.  Thanks. Doug

Answer (score 0):

This caught me out as well the first time I needed to do the same.

```
naDate <- structure(NA_real_, class="Date")
```

is what you need (assuming you want to set `ReferenceDate` to `NA`)...

**Edit**

This works for me

```
df <- read.table(text='Date     Location
2014-10-30     AB1
                 2014-09-02     AB3
                 2015-10-15     AB1
                 2016-11-02     AB4',header=T,stringsAsFactors=F)

df <- df %>% 
         mutate(
           Reference=ifelse(
                       row_number() == 3, 
                       structure(NA_real_, class="Date"), 
                       Date
                     )
         )
df
        Date Location  Reference
1 2014-10-30      AB1 2014-10-30
2 2014-09-02      AB3 2014-09-02
3 2015-10-15      AB1       <NA>
4 2016-11-02      AB4 2016-11-02
```

If it doesn't work for you, would you post some more details please? [Input data, code you tried, error message.  Thanks.]

Comment: Limey, I added your code to the 'df$Location <- NA' step from Daniel, but received this error: 
do not know how to convert 'value' to class “Date”

Answer (score 0):

Bit of a tricky one. In base-R

```
Reference.year <- format(Reference,"%Y")
dates.year <- format(df$Date,"%Y")

df$Location <- NA
df$Location[dates.year %in% Reference.year] <- do.call(c,lapply(dates.year,function(x) paste(Reference[Reference.year %in% x])))

        Date   Location
1 2014-10-30 2014-08-14
2 2014-09-02 2014-08-14
3 2015-10-15       <NA>
4 2016-11-02 2016-09-16
```

Data:

```
df <- read.table(text='Date     Location
2014-10-30     AB1
2014-09-02     AB3
2015-10-15     AB1
2016-11-02     AB4',header=T,stringsAsFactors=F)

Reference <- as.Date(c("2014-08-14", "2016-09-16"))
df$Date <- as.Date(df$Date)
```

Comment: Daniel, Thanks for the response.  I ran your code by received this error on the final step:   number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length

Comment: Here's what I have for code:
Records2$AerialDates<- as.Date(c("2014-08-28", "2017-10-26", '2019-06-19'))
Records2$ref.year <- format(Records2$AerialDates, "%Y")
Records2$dates.year <- format(Records2$Date, "%Y")
Records2$Location <-NA
Records2$Location[Records2$dates.year %in% Records2$ref.year] <-do.call(c,lapply(Records2$dates.year, function(x) paste))

Answer (score 0):

You can use tidyverse and lubridate (to easily extract the year). Specifically, You can use the `join` methods to merge the Date to the Reference instead of `ifelse`. Making a year column to line up the data will help this. See below:

```
# sample data
data <- tibble(Date = c("2014-10-30", "2014-09-02", "2015-10-15", "2016-11-02"), Location = c("AB1", "AB3", "AB1", "AB4"))

reference <- tibble(Reference = c("2014-08-14", "2016-09-16"))
```

```
library(lubridate)

# add year column to year reference
year_ref <- mutate(reference, year = year(Reference))

# add year column to data and left join to reference
data_with_ref <- data %>%
  mutate(year = year(Date)) %>%
  left_join(year_ref, by = "year") %>%
  select(-year)
```

Answer (score 0):

Base R solution:

```
df$Reference <- as.Date(reference$Reference)[match(as.Date(df$Date, "%Y"), 
                  as.Date(reference$Reference, "%Y"))]
```

Data:

```
df <- data.frame(Date = c("2014-10-30", "2014-09-02", "2015-10-15", "2016-11-02"), 
                 Location = c("AB1", "AB3", "AB1", "AB4"))

reference <- data.frame(Reference = c("2014-08-14", "2016-09-16"))
```